# Excel VBA: Run a Formula as long as there is a value in Another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Column A.
I have a formula in Column B.

```
=CONCAT("Test",":",LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))
```

I want the Formula to run so long as there is data in Column A.

```
Column A  Column B
3032-215  Test:3032
3031-158  Test:3031
4005-169  Test:4005
```

I am trying to write this so it autofills Column B as long as there is data in Column A.

Comment: (a) Your data in your example wouldn't be produced by that formula (b) What part of this are you having difficulties? Finding the last used cell in column A? Inserting the formula into the range?  Writing the formula so that it doesn't give a 1004 error? Please update your question to explain what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated it. The formula is giving me the correct results in Excel, but I want that column to auto to run so long as a value is in Column A.

At the moment, I am copying the formula into new rows within the column, but I figured it could be automated throughout the column in VBA.

Comment: If you say "I am trying to write this ..." it is usually a good idea to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted a VBA solution, then a Private Sub would do the trick.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Dim MyRange As Range, c As Range, LastRow As Integer

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

        For Each c In MyRange

            If c.Value <> "" Then

                c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=concat(""Test"","":"",LEFT(RC1,4))"

            End If

        Next c

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @YowE3K.  I've made an adjustment that I think works just as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try both. Both are really great solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Change CONCATENATE back to CONCAT as required.

It's now just nested in an IF function that first checks if the cell is empty. If not, it does what you want. If the cell *is* empty, it fills with a blank string.

```
=IF(A2<>0, CONCATENATE("Test",":",LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)), "")
```

edit: if you're worried about the blank string effecting whether excel sees 'data' as there or not (it will be an issue if you're using COUNT type functions as times), then there's no way around this without using VBA unfortunately.

Comment: This could work. It solves the issue immediately since it can be applied to all cells in the row. I guess I was looking at VBA in case it went outside of the applicable range

Comment: So you want VBA to detect how far down your column extends, and then fill the corresponding next column as needed with the applicable formula?

Comment: Yes that is the gist. The Formula that you gave works non-VBA since it returns no value if there is nothing in Column A which is the desired outcome. I guess I am just slightly worries about the data not filling all rows since Ive only pre-selected 1000 rows. I doubt that would happen, but it is possible but easily adjustable

Comment: kevin9999 has provided pretty much what you're after, but if you're going to go that route, you could also consider using VBA to do the string manipulation instead of just pasting the formula in.

    `c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=concat(""Test"","":"",RC1)"`

can be replaced with something like:

    `c.Offset(0, 1).value = "Test:" & Left(c, InStr(c, "-") - 1)`